# Reverse Dom traversing

Tags: javascript, css

I started to learn JavaScript and I am creating a navigation component in svelte and needed to add some sort of CSS visualization when there is a dropdown multiple levels deep. so I can see which parents nodes are connected with my "current-item" CSS class.

the visualization I use for this project is a color.

I came up with this logic:

```
https://codepen.io/Digi4Care/pen/YzaJbdW
```

The logic I use to determine when I reach the beginning of the node:

```
"LI" == node?.parentNode?.parentNode?.parentNode?.nodeName
```

I am wondering if there is another and more efficient way to do this?

Comment: This may help you, [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: Please do not use external links to show your code, as it's not guaranteed to be static, and not always accessible by all readers. Instead, please [edit] your question to include your code as a [mcve] in the question itself. Include the shortest code necessary in order for others to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Svelte - there's the [`<svelte:self>`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-self) element to create such a structure recursively. [This is the tutorial lesson](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-self).

When passing the `file` object instead of just the `name` to the `File` component, the `currentFile` can then be saved to a store on click. (How do you set the `current-menu-item`? Based on the url) This value can be used inside the `Folder` component to set a conditional class, if it's an ancestor.

```
function isAncestor(files, cF) {
    return files.includes(cF) ||  files.some(file => file.files && isAncestor(file.files, cF))
}
```

```
class:current-ancestor={isAncestor(files, $currentFile)}
```

[Here's a REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/554ffcdd99674761ad96f5024eb38b9a?version=3.49.0) with the complete example

Comment: ah ofc much better approach. thx for your help